# Junit for google guice injectioning

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have a class Dummy.java, who's constructor is annotated with @Inject.

```
@Inject
public Dummy() {
  this.injector = TestDummy.getInjector();
  init();
}
```

In the init(), I am injecting various dependencies like :

```
private void init() {
  this.tester = injector.getInstance(tester.class);
  this.jack = injector.getInstance(jack.class);   
}
```

Now when I am writing junit for Dummy.java, I am not getting how to inject these dependencies ? Any leads would be appraciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're being explicit about your Injector. Ideally, you should receive your dependencies (Tester and Jack) through your constructor, without needing to set an Injector.

```
@Inject
public Dummy(Tester tester, Jack jack) {
  this.tester = tester;
  this.jack = jack;
}
```

Now in your tests, you can call this `public` constructor manually, and pass in whichever Tester or Jack instance you want, including (but not requiring) a test double or mock.

```
Dummy dummy = new Dummy(new UnitTestTester(), mockJack);
```

Because you've annotated the instance with `@Inject`, you don't need to worry about Injector: As long as you get a copy of Dummy from an Injector, it will read that constructor and pass in your Tester and Jack instances.

```
public class YourDummyConsumer {
  @Inject public YourDummyConsumer(Dummy dummy) { /* ... */ }
}
```

`getInstance` is still useful, but typically you'll only see it at the very top level, in your Application class or your `public static void main(String[] args)` method:

```
Dummy dummy = injector.getInstance(dummy);
```

Comment: I have 15 parameters in total, that is why i cannot take them in the constructor (against the coding standards). That is why had to do it this way.

Comment: @IllegalSkillsException If you have 15 parameters, that is a strong indication that _your class is doing too much_ and should be refactored into two or three smaller, more-focused classes. (Besides, I have a nagging suspicion that the coding standards are in place exactly to discourage cases like yours, and that working around the rule is likely to cause more trouble down the line.)